# Graph DB Gremlin query for nested properties

Tags: azure, gremlin, graph-databases, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am storing the below data in azure cosmos graph db.

```
 "properties": {
        "A": {
          "value": "prop1 new value"
        },
        "settings": {
          "DigitalInput": {
            "Input1": {
              "nTransIn1": {
                "tagName": {
                  "value": ""
                }
              }
            },
            "Input2": {
              "nTransIn2": {
                "tagName": {
                  "value": ""
                }
              }
            }
```

When I am trying to query by single property

```java
g.V().has('s_objectId',within('9d8cf5c6-7b5f-4d0b-af70-bf516f219d73')).
valueMap("p_A")
```

is giving expected output but how to retrieve with property 'settings' which has nested properties. When I try

```java
g.V().has('s_objectId',within('9d8cf5c6-7b5f-4d0b-af70-bf516f219d73')).
valueMap("p_settings")
```

it is not giving the correct output as the setting property is stored like below in graph database

```
 "p_settings.DigitalInput.Input1.nTransIn1.tagName": [
        {
          "id": "6057e448-a2e8-48e4-820f-5396003bdcae",
          "value": ""
        }
      ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Your queries and sample data seem to use different field names. It would be helpful if you could add to the question an `addV` step that creates the structure you are using in a way that can be tested with TinkerGraph.

In general with Gremlin, the way to access map structures is to `select` your way into it. Something like

```java
valueMap("p_A").select("p_settings")
```