# How to store nested structure in graph database

Tags: database, nested, gremlin, graph-databases, hierarchical-data

I am analyzing how to store nested/hierarchical structure in graph database. I want to store like a tree where settings vertex will have two children DigitalInput and Input2 and like in subsequent parameters. Any inputs for which approach I should choose and how?

```
"properties": {
        "A": {
          "value": "prop1 new value"
        },
        "settings": {
          "DigitalInput": {
            "Input1": {
              "nTransIn1": {
                "tagName": {
                  "value": ""
                }
              }
            },
            "Input2": {
              "nTransIn2": {
                "tagName": {
                  "value": ""
                }
              }
            }
}
```

Comment: Is this related to your other question on this topic, or is the question here about how to decompose/shred the JSON like structure into nodes, edges and properties? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73617805/graph-db-gremlin-query-for-nested-properties

Comment: @KelvinLawrence I have created this structure in the workspace

https://gremlify.com/nnkqf4zp34q

The output I want which shows the nested properties for ex. digitalInput shows input1 and input2